# MySql INSERT statement is inserting a '0' rather than variable contents

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple INSERT statement which looks like this...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (`user_id`, `profile_id`, `comment`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['user_id']}', ('$problemID'), ('$comment'))") or die(mysql_error());
```

Everything is being inserted fine apart from the $problemID variable. In the MySql table it is just returning a 0. The table is set up to receive integers up to 11 characters.

The variable itself is set on a different page but is retrieved using this...

```
$problemID = intval( $_GET["problem"]);
```

If I echo the $problemID I get the correct number so I'm unsure as to why it won't just insert this number into my table. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Your projection has ``profile_id``, is that the same as `$problemID`? If not, then you might be trying to insert a value into a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: why enclosed it is brackets ?

Comment: Does any error occure? Or does the query run fine?

Comment: The query runs fine it just inserts a 0 rather than the correct number. The column does exist, it's a little confusing if you haven't seen it before but once it is working I will be cleaning everything up. As for the brackets, that's the way I have been taught and it has worked for other INSERT statments.

Comment: Sorted it now guys. The comments form was submitting to 'problem.php' rather than 'problem.php?problem=<?php echo $problemID; ?>'. Adding this has fixed it.

Thanks for the help I would have been here all day checking INSERT statement otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your comment is more clearly sanitized; Try something like this:

```
mysql_query( sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO 
        comments (`user_id`, `profile_id`, `comment`) 
    VALUES     
        (%s, %s, '%s')",
    intval( $_SESSION['user_id'] ),
    intval( $problemID ),
    mysql_real_escape_string( $comment )
)) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Just to be thorough, make sure that your table has a separate primary index (aka entry ID) with **auto-increment** tacked on. It could be that your MySQL insertion is working fine, however, the receiving table doesn't know that it should keep appending entries.

Comment: I've tried your code and the same occurs. I do have an 'id' column with auto increment selected so it can't be that.

Comment: Just to be absolutely certain, can you do a MySQL export of just the table structure you're inserting into, and add to problem?

Comment: Fixed it now it was a problem with the form action rather than the PHP or MySql. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that your INSERT query is referring to the wrong column in your comments table, as you have the following:

```
INSERT INTO comments (`user_id`, `profile_id`, `comment`)
```

but you're referring to a variable named `$problemID`, so my guess is that you meant something like this:

```
INSERT INTO comments (`user_id`, `problem_id`, `comment`)
```

Perhaps you copied and pasted the query code but forgot to change the column name in the projection?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, otherwise he would not be able to insert the row all together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets and try to add the variables rather than including them into the string.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (`user_id`, `profile_id`, `comment`)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', ".$problemID.", '".mysql_real_escape_string($comment)."')") or die(mysql_error());
```